# Excel INDEX and MATCH function, unsure how to get exact corresponding cell with Attached Example

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, rank

I have a list of customers down the left side of my table and a list of resellers along the top of the table.

In the cells are the number of widgets purchased by the customer from the reseller.

I need a way to get the top 4 resellers per customer based on the units purchased.

I've attached an excel file with the formula I was using, which isn't quite perfect. If there are duplicate values in the row, it always brings back the 1st matched reseller, where I actually want to bring back the reseller name that the value corresponds to. I've put in green cells what I want the yellow cell to show.

Please see my table below, I hope it provides enough info

[image: Table]

```html
<table>
<thead><tr><th>CustomerID</th><th>Reseller A</th><th>Reseller B</th><th>Reseller C</th><th>Reseller D</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>10001</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>78</td><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>10002</td><td>4</td><td>7</td><td>43</td><td>6</td></tr>
 <tr><td>10003</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>5</td><td>7</td></tr>
 <tr><td>10004</td><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>34</td><td>65</td></tr>
 <tr><td>10005</td><td>8</td><td>4</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

My formula would work if each value in the row was unique, but that's not the case unfortunately.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.
Stefan.

Comment: Just for reference, here is my formula: =IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$AN$1,MATCH(IFERROR(LARGE($B2:$AN2,1),"None"),$B2:$AN2,0)),"No Match")

Comment: You need to adjust the *k* parameter of LARGE with a COUNTIF to overcome duplicate qtys.

Comment: I don't get how the COUNTIF would work here, any chance you could amend the formula to help explain?

Comment: Sure, just as soon as I find the time to retype all of your data into a [mcve] so that any formula I provide will be thoroughly tested.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @StefanHanotin he was being sarcastic.  please load the data in text form so we can copy and paste.

Comment: Please edit the original post with the data and not the comments,  comments cannot be formatted.

Comment: Okay, that should be easier to do. I've attached a html table now. (I have no idea why but the text version with all of the ---| didn't format correctly and looked ridiculous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following formula in F2:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B2:$E2=LARGE($B2:$E2,COLUMN(A:A)))*(COUNTIF($E2:E2,$B$1:$E$1)=0),),0))
```

Copy over 4 columns and down the length of the data set.  Only this one formula for all.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million Scott, this is exactly it. You sir, are a legend. I will work out how this works and if I get stuck come back to you for a little explanation if you wouldn't mind.